# how to access default style of material-ui tooltip?

Tags: material-ui

I have IconButton and I want to access the default style of the tooltip (ie access tooltipStyles). How to do that?

```
<IconButton tooltip="link" tooltipStyles={oldStyle+newStyle} />
```

oldStyle is the default style but I dont know how to access the default style.

Answer (score 0):

"A bit" late but might help others.
You need to wrap your component in a `muiThemeable` HOC

```
import muiThemeable from 'material-ui/styles/muiThemeable';

const MyIcon = props => 
   // props.muiTheme.tooltip 

muiThemeable()(MyIcon);
```